# Função php não insere registros no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma função php que insere dois tipos de registro em uma tabela Mysql, de acordo com a escolha do usuário em um combobox. A primeira opção do combo insere os registros normalmente, porém quando escolho a segunda ele não insere e não acusa erro nenhum. No inspect element vejo que todos os parâmetros do form estão sendo passados corretamente.
Alguém pode me ajudar ? Obrigada

Segue o código:

```
if($funcao == 'email') {

$sql = "select * from mensageminterna where mensagem like '%<a h%';";
$rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

    if($option == 'corretor'){

        $sql = "insert into mensageminterna (codempresa, codusuarioremetente, codusuario, mensagem, icone, datacriacao)
                select u.codempresa, u1.codusuario, u.codusuario, '$texto', 'cool', now()  from usuario u
                inner join usuario u1 on u.codempresa=u1.codempresa and u1.email like 'admin@%' and u1.indadministrador=1
                where u.codsituacaousuario=1;";
        $rst = my_execute($connW, $sql);

} elseif($option == 'gestor'){

        $sql = "insert into mensageminterna (codempresa, codusuarioremetente, codusuario, mensagem, icone, datacriacao)
            select u.codempresa, u1.nome remetente, u.nome destinatario, u.codtipousuario, '$texto', 'cool', now()  from usuario u
            inner join usuario u1 on u.codempresa=u1.codempresa and u1.email like 'admin@%' and u1.indadministrador=1
            inner join tipousuario tu on tu.codtipousuario = u.codtipousuario
            where u.codsituacaousuario=1 and tu.nome like '%geren%' or tu.nome like '%diret%' or tu.nome like '%coord%' or tu.nome like '%adm%'  or tu.nome like '%super%';";
        $rst = my_execute($connW, $sql);

} else {
        echo "Não enviado";
    }

exit;
}

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).on('click', '#btnEnviar', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#funcao").val("email");
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/email-broadcast.php",
            type: "POST",
            timeout:default_timeout,
            data: $('#formemail').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                self.attr('disabled', 'true');
            },
            success: function() {
                alert("Enviado com sucesso !");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                console.log(textStatus, jqXHR);
            },
            complete: function(){
                self.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });

</script>


<form method="post" name="formemail" action="/email-broadcast.php" id="formemail">
        <input type="hidden" name="funcao" id="funcao" value="email"/>


            <label style="margin-left: 7px">Destinatário:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="destinatario" id="destinatario" style="width: 250px;">
                <option value="corretor" id="corretor" name="corretor">Corretores</option>
                <option value="gestor" id="gestor" name="gestor">Gestores</option>
            </select>



        <textarea cols="86" rows="15" id="scriptenvio" name="scriptenvio" style=" margin-top: 10px;">
            Blá blá blá
        </textarea><br>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

---

[image: select 2ª query]

peguei o select da segunda query (a que não estava inserindo) e ela me retornou 464 registros.

Comment: Qual API está usando para conectar com o banco de dados? poderia mostrar onde é feita a atribuição de `$option`?

Comment: Uso a mysqli...

Comment: E a atribuição de `$option` onde está?

Comment: `global $option;`
`$option = postget('destinatario');`

fica antes do início da função

Comment: Veja se o banco retornou algum erro, com `mysql_error($conexao);` faça um if na chamada de `mysqli_query()` ou `mysqli_execute()`

Comment: Então... a função my_excecute já trata as excessões: 

`try {`
  `$before = microtime(true);`
  `if (! mysqli_query ( $conn, $query )) {`
   `if (IS_DEV) {`
    `echo "<hr>DB ERROR: " . mysqli_error ( $conn ) .` `"<hr>";`
   `}`
   `addLog ( 'db.log', $query . '|'.$paginaatual.'|'. `mysqli_error ( $conn ) );`
   `throw new Exception(mysqli_error ( $conn ));`
   `#exit();`
  }

Comment: Então não existem registros que satisfacam as condições do select. Você pode tentar copiar a consulta e testar direto no banco com valores simulados(os mesmos enviados no form) e ver se retorna algo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31063/discussion-between-donna-the-girl-and-rray).

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso ao chat xD

Comment: Vou mandar print em resposta

Comment: Retira aquele `exit;` do código, ele parece perdido ...

Comment: A tua função `my_execute()` retorna erro ao falhar ? A mensagem _"não enviado"_ tem apenas efeito se a variável `$opcao` não for igual a `gestor` ou `corretor`.

Comment: Não retorna erro nenhum, inclusive eu recebo o alerta de mensagem enviada e todos os parâmetros são passados no form data

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido!

Na verdade, eu estava tentando inserir dados varchar em campos int na segunda query. Ficou assim a correta:

```
} elseif($option == 'gestor'){

    $sql = "insert into mensageminterna (codempresa, codusuarioremetente, codusuario, mensagem, icone, datacriacao)
        select u.codempresa, u1.codusuario, u.codusuario, '$texto', 'cool', now()  from usuario u
        inner join usuario u1 on u.codempresa=u1.codempresa and u1.email like 'admin@%' and u1.indadministrador=1
        inner join tipousuario tu on tu.codtipousuario = u.codtipousuario
        where u.codsituacaousuario=1 and tu.nome like '%geren%' or tu.nome like '%diret%' or tu.nome like '%coord%' or tu.nome like '%adm%'  or tu.nome like '%super%';";
    $rst = my_execute($connW, $sql);

}
```

Muito obrigada a todos pela ajuda !

Comment: Então sua função não trata as excessões, pq você falou nenhum erro era exibido.